# How To close the navigation drawer with hardware(android) back button?

Tags: navigation-drawer, react-native

I am using `react-native-drawer-layout` for navigation drawer.

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
    drawerWidth={100}
    ref={'Drawer'}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Right}
    renderNavigationView={() => NavigationView}
/>
```

When i try to close the `drawer` total app is getting closed.

Could anybody let me know how to close the drawer with hardware(android) button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never user DrawerLayoutAndroid but according to the [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#content) it has method "closeDrawer()" that is supposed to close it... by using [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html) you should add an event listener to the component containing the drawer layout, add this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', ()=>{
        this.refs.Drawer.closerDrawer();
        return true;
        });
}
```

Comment: it worked exactly. Thank you so much for your help. Could you tell or provide any link to know about what 'return true' statement is doing.

Comment: @Kishore you return true when you are handling the back press, and false when you want the back press to act as default with being handled.